# How do I change segmentedControl to work in swift 3.0?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to change the line `segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "mapTypeChanged:", for: .valueChanged)` to work in swift 3.0. As far as I know `"mapTypeChanged:"` is an arbitrary name and could be anything so its not a function I've made anywhere else. From all the other sources online i'm told to put `segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(class.mapTypeChanged, for: .valueChanged)` but I don't know of any classes associated with that?

The function declaration after the line is:

```
func mapTypeChanged(segControl: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch segControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            mapView.mapType = .standard
        case 1:
            mapView.mapType = .hybrid
        case 2:
            mapView.mapType = .satellite
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

What do I do to fix this? Thanks.

I'm going through a book and thats where I got the original line but it was written before swift 3.0. Up to this point Xcode has done a good job of making the changes for me but this one doesn't run properly after I make the suggested changes. I'm stuck.

SOLVED:`segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mapTypeChanged), for: .valueChanged)`

I feel stupid now cause there was a function defined literally right after it that I wrote myself. My mind was drawing a blank and I just wasn't connecting the dots. Never the less I still didn't know how the syntax for swift 3.0 was for the original code in question. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Are you sure its arbitrary? From what I understand it seems that your book is telling you to create function that responds to when the value of your segmentedControl changes.

Comment: Agreed. You are missing something we can't easily help. mapTypeChanged: **is not** arbitrary, but is something specific to what you are working on. It may be specific to "class" (or more likely, a class name specific to what you are working on), but this is something you need to figure out. It's not a simple Swift version migration, nor anything that deals with UISegmentedControl in general. Don't blame Xcode - blame you! (Trust me, my joke is my code work first time every time. HAH!)

Comment: Well the book tells me to add the line I mentioned above and a function definition below it which maybe is what you are referring to but Idk what class it is associated with? I'll edit the original post to provide the function that the book told me to write below the line first line.

Comment: @Jakeunderscore Why did you assume it was arbitrary in the first place if it was defined in your book?

Comment: @Jakeunderscore u got it working. How u can achieve that can you post here or mark as expected if any of below answer is working or post your answer so other can can get help

Comment: @benjamin Lowry Because in the book they had me write the segmentedControl line before writing the function and for some reason it didnt click with me that the function was supposed to be separate from the loadView override function so I thought the function just based the name off of the "mapTypeChanged" because it was in quotes, like it was a string or something. I didn't quite understand what was happening in that line but Its cleared up. And yes i'll go ahead and add the solution. Thanks for bring it up.

Comment: That's not what he meant by the answer comment. On SO you are supposed to mark an answer as correct. You will be able to click a green check mark next to an answer to mark it as correct. In this case it would be @matt's answer.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry Oh I see what you are saying. Thanks for clarifying. I think I fixed it.

Comment: @Jakeunderscore Yeah you got it. It's just better that an answer is marked for future viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

```
 action: #selector(mapTypeChanged),
```

and all will be well.

Comment: Yeah, now that he has included the func (which would have been helpful before) I completely agree with this answer.

Comment: I got it thank you! I was kind of dumb and forgot I had to put the function outside of the overloaded function which all of this was in. But I got it working, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.mapTypeChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: . valueChanged)
```